# How do I dynamically join one table to multiple other tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am currently searching my database for all column name's that have a particular substring using the below code.

```
SELECT 
    t.name AS table_name,
    SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
    c.name AS column_name
INTO 
    #Tables
FROM
    sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE 
    c.name LIKE '%foo%'
ORDER BY 
    schema_name, table_name;
```

I want to take the table and column names this query returns and join each of them to another table like below.

```
SELECT *
FROM #ReferenceTable rt
INNER JOIN #Tables.table_name t ON rt.ReferenceColumn = t.ColumnName
```

I believe this can be done through a dynamic query, but I haven't been able to figure out how.  My initial thought was to pass a table into `sp_executesql`, but I'm not sure that's possible. What is the correct way to join multiple table names to another table?

Comment: If you need to write dynamic SQL, I think the easiest way to write it is to visualise (or actually write out) what your query needs to look like if it weren't written dynamically and work backwards from that. I _believe_ you might be looking for something like `DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''; SELECT @SQL += 'SELECT * FROM #ReferenceTable rt JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + ' t ON rt.ReferenceColumn = t.' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ';' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%foo%'; EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;` or some modification of that maybe?

Comment: What is the logic here? How would you know that two tables need to be joined because both tables have a column with the characters foo in the name? And how would you handle finding 2 or more columns in a given table? Are you assuming that any table will have one and only one matching column name and that the returned column can be joined to any other table based on that? Given your example of foo what happens when you have FootballTeam and FoodName for columns? There are so many ways this can break.

Comment: @SeanLange The column name is actually BusinessUnit.  I am verifying visually that the columns that are returned by the first query are the ones I am looking for.  I have a central table that specifies the business unit so I am trying to verify that BusinessUnit in all these other tables map to the correct BusinessUnit in the central table.

Comment: Also, how do you know which table to use as the main table of your query? Does this really need to be dynamic? How often are you adding new tables where you need to continue to see every column? Seems to me that creating a view from the tables you need would be a better approach in almost every situation.

Comment: If you have foreign keys then you can do this systematically with dynamic SQL only passing the source table and target table(s). If you do not have foreign keys then you need to also pass the source columns and target columns to join on. Do you have foreign keys?